# How to match a string on a prefix and get the rest?

Tags: scala, match

I can write the code like this:

```
str match {
    case s if s.startsWith("!!!") => s.stripPrefix("!!!")
    case _ =>
}
```

But I want to know is there any better solutions. For example:

```
str match {
    case "!!!" + rest => rest
    case _ =>
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
val r = """^!!!(.*)""".r
val r(suffix) = "!!!rest of string"
```

So `suffix` will be populated with **rest of string**, or a `scala.MatchError` gets thrown.

A different variant would be:

```
val r = """^(!!!){0,1}(.*)""".r
val r(prefix,suffix) = ...
```

And `prefix` will either match the !!! or be null. e.g.

```
(prefix, suffix) match {
   case(null, s) => "No prefix"
   case _ => "Prefix"
}
```

The above is a little more complex than you might need, but it's worth looking at the power of Scala's regexp integration.

Answer (score 20):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's now possible to pattern match a `String` by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
"!!!hello" match {
  case s"!!!$rest" => rest
  case _           => "oups"
}
// "hello"
```

Comment: What an amazing feature!

Answer (score 16):

If it's the sort of thing you do often, it's probably worth creating an extractor

```
object BangBangBangString{ 
   def unapply(str:String):Option[String]= {
       str match {
          case s if s.startsWith("!!!") => Some(s.stripPrefix("!!!"))
          case _ => None
       }
   }
}
```

Then you can use the extractor as follows

```
str match{
   case BangBangBangString(rest) => println(rest)
   case _ => println("Doesn't start with !!!")
}
```

or even

```
for(BangBangBangString(rest)<-myStringList){
   println("rest")
}
```

Comment: instead of making a single user extractor, you could make a class like Prefix extractor with the first parameter of the startsWith argument and then use it like: `val BandBangBangString = new PrefixExtractor("!!!")`

Answer (score 6):

Good question ! 
Even i was trying a lot to find out the answer.

Here is a [good link where I found the answer](http://npntraining.com/blog/2017/match-expressions-with-pattern-guards/)

```
object _04MatchExpression_PatternGuards {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val url: String = "Jan";

    val monthType = url match {
      case url if url.endsWith(".org")   => "Educational Websites";
      case url if url.endsWith(".com")   => "Commercial Websites";
      case url if url.endsWith(".co.in") => "Indian Websites"
      case _                             => "Unknow Input";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answers a different question.